# Howler.js not working on Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, web-audio-api, howler.js

I am using the following script and its working fine in all browsers except IE(11). The main function of this script is to redirect sound in the right or left side of the earphone.
in all browsers its working fine but in IE, its redirecting sound on both sides.

```
var sound = new Howl({
    src: ['1kHz.mp3'],
});
var id = sound.play();
sound.stereo (1.0, id);
```

Kindly help out me to solve this error

Comment: Has this anything to do with PHP?

Comment: No, it does not have anything with PHP, just the above script used @NigelRen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stereo sound only works when there is Web Audio support, but Internet Explorer only has HTML5 Audio. There is nothing you can do to get around this in that browser.